# Why is RegisterDragDrop refusing to work?

Tags: winapi, rust, drag-and-drop, webview2, tauri

I'm trying to implement a custom file drag drop handler for tauri (since the inbuilt one for tauri doesn't include data about the drop effect).

I'm creating a drag drop handler struct and then calling RegisterDragDrop

```rs
unsafe {
    let window_hwnd = HWND(window.hwnd().expect("Failed to get window hwnd").0);

    let mut drag_drop_handler = ManuallyDrop::new(DragDropHandler::new());

    RegisterDragDrop(
        window_hwnd,
        &IDropTarget::from(ManuallyDrop::take(&mut drag_drop_handler))
    ).expect("Failed to register drag and drop handler");

    return Some(move || {
        ManuallyDrop::drop(&mut drag_drop_handler);
    });
}
```

Ignore all the ManuallyDrop stuff, that's just so I can manually drop the DragDropHandler when the window is closed.

then the DragDropHandler struct

```rs
#[implement(IDropTarget)]
pub struct DragDropHandler {}

impl DragDropHandler {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
impl IDropTarget_Impl for DragDropHandler {
    fn DragEnter(
        &self,
        pdataobj: Option<&IDataObject>,
        grfkeystate: MODIFIERKEYS_FLAGS,
        pt: &POINTL,
        pdweffect: *mut DROPEFFECT
    ) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
        println!("Drag Enter");
        Ok(())
    }

    fn DragLeave(&self) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
        println!("Drag Leave");
        Ok(())
    }

    fn DragOver(
        &self,
        grfkeystate: MODIFIERKEYS_FLAGS,
        pt: &POINTL,
        pdweffect: *mut DROPEFFECT
    ) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
        println!("Drag Over");
        Ok(())
    }

    fn Drop(
        &self,
        pdataobj: Option<&IDataObject>,
        grfkeystate: MODIFIERKEYS_FLAGS,
        pt: &POINTL,
        pdweffect: *mut DROPEFFECT
    ) -> windows::core::Result<()> {
        println!("Drag Drop");
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

And I don't really think there's anything wrong with my code, but instead I think the problem is that webview2 is just interfering with what I'm trying to do. I've found that when dragging files onto the window now, my struct doesn't pick up the events, but when I drop it on my window, webview2 opens up a new window to display the contents of it.

I assume that webview2 is calling RevokeDragDrop on my struct before adding it's own drag drop handler, because before I disabled the inbuilt tauri drag drop handler, I had to call RevokeDragDrop before adding my own, otherwise it would throw an error.

Anyway, does anyone know how I could disable the webview2 drag drop handler from tauri?

Comment: *"Ignore all the ManuallyDrop stuff"* - but I can't look away! Especially since its UB to use the value after [`ManuallyDrop::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/struct.ManuallyDrop.html#method.take), but you do by calling `ManuallyDrop::drop` later.

Comment: By extension, what you're passing to `RegisterDragDrop` is being pulled out of `drag_drop_handler` and subsequently dropped after the call.

Comment: I implemented Drop on my struct and added a print statement, and it doesn't print out until my window closes, so I think what I'm doing is probably correct.

Comment: Nope, definite UB is not "probably correct", you're not special, you can't violate the rules and expect anything to work.

Comment: Alright then, well how should I approach this?